# restricting text to a certain width with css or php

Tags: php, html, css

I have text that I put into a div, which is generated automatically by php..(taken from the database).

But the text stretches over the div.

here is an example of what I want to do:

```
<div>
<?php 
     Generate_All_Text_Content_Here();
?>
</div>
```

I want the div to limit to where the text stretches..say no more than 300px.

I tried to give it width measurement..but it has no influence over the div element

Comment: @sandeep There it is ;).

Comment: how does the text stretch over the div? thats not how the default box model works.

Answer (score 4):

add to your style

```
div{
  max-width:300px;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  text-overflow:<clip> or <ellipsis>;
  overflow:<hidden> or <scroll>;
}
```

this should really cover everything >.<

Comment: Missing:
`white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: white-space:nowrap; is a bad idea, since it puts everything onto a single line which would be a bad idea with fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this then?

```
<div style="<?php echo get_text_width(); ?>">
    <?php Generate_All_Text_Content_Here(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: and how do you `get_text_width()`?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the div width with CSS and text won't be bigger:

```
div {
  max-width: 300px; /*Or simply width: 300px; if you want the div always to be that width*/
}
```